How to import LFR synthetic multiplex dataset with ground truth
I am an amateur Python programmer who recently started working in the field of complex networks.
For research in the field of multiplex graphs, I need one or more multiplex datasets that have ground truth so that I can use them for community detection in multiplex networks and use the NMI metric to measure the quality of the final communities produced. to measure with ground truth communities.
But since most real-world multiplex datasets do not have ground truth, we need to perform some of our analysis on synthetic datasets that do have ground truth.
Therefore, friends who have special expertise in this field are invited to share their experiences with my humble servant so that I can use them.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
